# identify if present and remove specific argument from shell args

Tags: arguments, getopts

I have to check if particular argument lets say 'java8' is present in my shell arguments to script and if it is present remove it . Also I want it to be stored in some other variable  , but want it to be removed from my $*.

One option I Trie checking if arg is present using getopts  but I dont know how to remove argument .

Please note - the position of arg to check 'java8' is not known I can be at any place

```
while getopts "f:" flag
do
     case $flag in
         f)
           echo $OPTARG
           ;;
     esac
done
echo $*
~
```

So basically when I invoke -

./test.sh arg1 arg2 -f java8 arg3

after execution of getopts block the remaining args will be

arg1 , arg2 , arg3

Comment: Which one do you want to remove, just `java8` or the two back-to-back arguments `-f` and `java8`? At first you only mention `java8`, but the code you have looks for the `-f` option, and your example involves `-f` and `java8`. I suppose you don't want to remove `-f` if it's followed by any other argument?

Comment: `getopts` can be used to process options passed the standard way as in `cmd -f java8 arg1 arg2 arg3`, `cmd -fjava8 -- arg1 arg2 arg3`. In standard option processing, you can't have options after non-options, so you can't use `getopts` to parse the options as seen in your example script invocation (unless you first remove those 2 arg1 arg2 before the first options before processing the first invocation of `getopts`).

Comment: Do you want the arguments removed so later code in the script will not see them, or do you also want the arguments to no longer be visible in process listings  `ps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this? I'm assuming you want to remove `-f java8`...

```
#!/bin/bash

while (( $# )); do
    if [[ $1 = "-f" ]] && [[ $2 = "java8" ]]; then
        shift 2
        continue
    fi

    args+=( "$1" )
    shift
done

echo "${args[*]}"
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./argtest.sh one two three
one two three
$ ./argtest.sh one two -f java8 three four
one two three four
$ ./argtest.sh -f java8 -f foo -f bar
-f foo -f bar
```

Comment: This works but i want to retain $* which is very critical for script to take on rest of parameters

Answer (score 1):

For any POSIX shell (without using a temporary array):  Dropping any instance of `-f` followed by `java8`, or of `-fjava8`, from the list of positional parameters, while counting the number of such dropped options-with arguments in the variable `found`.

```bash
skip=0 found=0
for arg do
    case $1 in
        -f)
            if [ "$2" = java8 ]; then
                skip=2
                found=$(( found + 1 ))
            fi
            ;;
        -f*)
            if [ "$1" = -fjava8 ]; then
                skip=1
                found=$(( found + 1 ))
            fi
    esac

    if [ "$skip" -eq 0 ]; then
        set -- "$@" "$1"
    else
        skip=$(( skip - 1 ))
    fi
    shift
done

if [ "$skip" -eq 1 ]; then
    set -- "$@" -f
    found=$(( found - 1 ))
fi

printf 'Args: %s\n' "$*"
printf 'Found = %d\n' "$found"
```

The above loop iterates as often as the initial number of positional parameters.

If the first positional parameter is `-f`, the second positional parameter is tested to see whether it's `java8`.  If the test is *true*, then we need to skip these two arguments, so the `skip` counter is set to 2.  We also increment `found` to indicate that we've found one more instance of `-f java8`.

If the first positional parameter is `-fjava8`, then we need to skip this single argument, so the `skip` counter is set to 1.  We also increment `found` to indicate that we've found one more instance of `-fjava8` (the same as finding `-f java8`).

After the `case` statement, we don't do anything other than decrement the `skip` counter and `shift` off the first positional parameter if `skip` is non-zero.  If `skip` is zero, we move the first positional parameter to the end of the list before calling `shift`, effectively allowing the arguments we keep to cycle back through the list while dropping the unwanted arguments.

Since we're using the list of positional parameters in a cyclic way, we would lose the last argument if it was `-f` and the first argument was `java8`.  This is what the last `if` statement protects against.